Windows operating system: how would one transliterate Windows into Russian and why?
If you permit me, I'd like to ask another question about Russian language—greatest language in the world.
How would you normally transliterate the word Windows into Russian, if it was a proper noun (the name of a well-known operating system)?
(Виндовс, Уиндовс, Виндовз, Уиндовз, Виндоус, Уиндоус, Виндоуз, Уиндоуз, «Окна», «Окошки», Windows or maybe everyone writes as he wants?)
https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4432246-kak-pravilno-po-russki-v-uindov-us-z-okna-ili-windows-pochemu.html
I am the author of that question!

I once saw, I think it was in Огонек, back in the 20th century, the phrase “Windowsовская система”. I will never forget it.


How would you normally transliterate the word Windows into Russian, if it was a proper noun (the name of a well-known operating system)?

You wouldn't.
By the time Windows (the OS) became a thing of any importance in the Russian-speaking world, it had already come to be perfectly acceptable to write English brand names in Russian texts using the Latin alphabet.
Shortly before that (roughly from the 1940s to the 1980s), the tendency was to use у for w and з for the final s: уоки-токи, уокмен, уайт-спирит, ноу-хау, Берроуз (Burroughs), Медоуз (Meadows) etc, with lots of ad-hoc exceptions: Виндроуз, Вилли Вонка, свинг, твист etc.
In the journalistic corpus, there are 14 entries of Виндоуз (obviously a name of a video game character) and 7 each of Уиндоуз and Виндоус.

Что значит You don't  в начале Вашего вопроса? Не совсем понял.

@Alex ну то что просто не нужно транслитерировать никак) (это ответ на ваш вопрос "как транслитерировать" - "никак (не нужно)"

Хм, но у меня исключительно советские пишущие машинки. "Любава", "Ортех", "Украина". Пользуюсь по жизни только ими. Как Вам такой поворот дела, а?

@Alexander: I didn't know you could post to Stack Exchange from a Soviet typewriter! Word renditions, as most other things language, form through, for the lack of a better word, public consensus. The majority of Russian speakers these days do possess the knowledge of the Latin alphabet and do have access to technology that allows typing it easily. Because of that, the way to render "Windows" in a Russian text these days is to type "Windows" in Latin script. If you are bound by self-imposed technological limitations and diverge from the mainstream usage, you'll have to blaze the trail yourself.

@Quassnoi, мой компьютер не печатает. У меня нет принтера. Я печатаю на машинке. Вопрос о том, как мне сделать именно печатный текст для себя. (Что выбрать: Виндовз, Уиндоус, винду или винты...). А в картриджах принтеров краска заканчивается за пару часов. А мама мне покупает одну конфетку за 5 молдавских банов в день. Ну а компьютер - папа еле-еле накопил за пару лет, с долгами.  Не верьте - приезжайте к нам и увидите, как нас обобрали румыны, растоптали, втоптали в грязь. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnDxHTaeNX0  (поставьте курсор на 6:00)

@Alexander: I'm very sorry to hear that. Being limited to a Cyrillic-only typeset is not a common situation for most Russian speakers these days (at least in Russia), so there is just not enough use cases for any kind of guidance. If you are typing for yourself, just pick the option that is the most aesthetically pleasing to you. Good luck!

Спасибо большое, уважаемый Quassnoi. Пособие по инвалидности 2000 леев, а коммуналка 7000.  Можете не верить, я понимаю. На бирже труда у румын проклятых стоял три года, не дали работы, только орут с дьявольской ухмылкой: «Че, ту ну штий? Да че ту штий делок?». (Барин, да ведь он нас ни во что поставил!) В прошлом году боли в левой ноге были настолько невыносимые, что это хуже смерти, а зубов нет (мне 35). А учился-то я в русском лицее. Когда папа умрёт, меня же повесят за  неуплату.  Я молю Бога, чтобы я умер раньше, чем он.

Очень прошу простить за такое излияние, больше не буду. В любом случае Ваш ответ полезен и правилен. Действительно,  есть смысл оставить латиницу. Спасибо, что не заминусовали вопрос, не люблю минусов. Я с проекта БВ, там минусы крайне редки.
